# Implement a role and authorization concept with Wolkenkit?

Tags: wolkenkit

I recently started working with Wolkenkit and I was wondering if there is a possibility of implementing some sort of role concept yet?

I already found [Wolkenkit: ACLs for authorization and user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976860/wolkenkit-acls-for-authorization-and-user-roles) which is already quite interesting, and gives me a first idea on how to solve that, but at the same time it is not exactly what I need.

In my Use-Case I need a dynamic role concept which can be changed at any time in order to grant and revoke access to certain parts of my application.

Ideally it would be a mechanism that allows me to associate commands and events with multiple roles at run-time. Are there any new approaches on this topic or any examples where this is already done?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization concept of [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) is based on tokens.

Hence, the simplest thing to do is to have the identity provider add claims for roles, as described in [ACLs for authorization and user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978545/1333873) (which is the article you already linked to). This works out of the box, and you do not have to provide and special logic to your wolkenkit applications except to read the token and evaluate its claims. However, this is only suited for static role models, as you'd need to change the identity provider's configuration every time a role assignment changes.

If you require a more dynamic approach, right now unfortunately you are left to your own devices. What you could do is to add a property to your aggregate that contains an array of roles (or user IDs) that you want to be able to access the aggregate. Then, in each command, you would need to check the current user against this array. But still, this means that you have predefined roles, you just could allow or restrict access to aggregate at runtime for specific roles.

If you require an even more dynamic approach, such as making up roles ad-hoc, e.g. to share data with a group that you just want to create at hand, you end up with what we call *group-based authorization*. Right now, there is no support for this, and AFAIK nobody has yet implemented something like that. Support for this is on the [wolkenkit roadmap](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit/blob/master/roadmap.md), but right now unfortunately there is no ETA available (maybe this is something you could [contribute to wolkenkit](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/3.0.0/getting-started/contributing-to-wolkenkit/overview/)?).

Either way, you need to make sure that your identity provider is configured correctly and wolkenkit is setup accordingly, as described in [wolkenkit redirects to Auth0 even when user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266737/1333873).

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the core developers of wolkenkit, working at [the native web](https://www.thenativeweb.io/) (the company behind wolkenkit), so please take my answer with a grain of salt.*